# Pointwise limit of a "net" of measurable functions is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, nets

Let $(X, \mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space with the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and the measure $\mu$.

Let $B$ be a separable Banach space. Then, it is well-known from a theorem by Pettis that weak / strong measurability of a mapping $f:X \to B$ are equivalent.

Now let $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha \in J}$ be a net of measurable functions $f_\alpha : X \to B$ such that for a.e.$x \in X$, the net $(f_\alpha(x))_{\alpha \in J}$ in $B$ converges to some $f(x) \in B$.

Then, my question is that, is this mapping $x \to f(x)$ necessarily measurable?

I cannot judge myself easily because measure theory does not really work well with general nets..Could anyone help me?

Comment: This is more suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/  Indeed, here is (a generalization of) the counterexample... https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141198/442

Comment: In fact, ANY function on, say, $[0,1]$ is a limit of a net of measurable functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Let $N\subseteq[0,1]$ be a non-measurable set. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of indicator functions of finite subsets of $N$. Then $\mathcal{F}$ is a net under the pointwise ordering with limit $1_N$.